# What is the difference between auto deduction and template type deduction?

Tags: c++, templates, auto

Let we have the following code

```
    auto x = { 11, 23, 9 }; 
    template<typename T> // template with parameter
    void f(T param); 

    f({ 11, 23, 9 }); // error! can't deduce type for T
```

Here in the following code `auto` is deduced automatically while template is not deduced automatically.

- How `auto` type is deduced?
- what is `auto` type behind the scenes?

Comment: It is a good habit to cite the references, particularly when you have used content verbatim. From "Effective Modern C++" by Scott Meyers.

Comment: Sharing knowledge is a good thing. But you have to mention where you got it from especially if it involves using content from published copyrighted books.

Comment: It is not the question of my happiness. Copyrighted material can be taken down. See this post for example. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276012/dealing-with-a-claim-that-a-post-on-so-is-using-copyrighted-content-without-perm

Comment: auto type deduction is the same as template type deduction, except for braced initializers. Scott Meyers has explained clearly about this in the below cppcon 
https://youtu.be/wQxj20X-tIU

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`auto` type deduction is usually the same as template type deduction, but `auto`
type deduction assumes that a braced initializer represents a `std::initializer_list`, and template type deduction doesn’t.

When an `auto`–declared variable is initialized with a
braced initializer, the deduced type is an instantiation of `std::initializer_list`.
But if the corresponding template is passed the same initializer, type deduction fails,
and the code is rejected:

```
auto x = { 11, 23, 9 }; // x's type is     
                       //std::initializer_list<int>
template<typename T> // template with parameter
void f(T param); // template with parameter
```

However, if you specify in the template that param is a `std::initializer_list<T>`
for some unknown T, template type deduction will deduce what T is:

```
template<typename T>
void f(std::initializer_list<T> initList);
f({ 11, 23, 9 }); // T deduced as int, and initList's
 // type is std::initializer_list<int>
```

> ### Remember
>
> - auto type deduction is usually the same as template type deduction, but auto type deduction assumes that a braced initializer represents a
>     `std::initializer_list`, and template type deduction doesn’t.

Comment: It is a good habit to cite the references, particularly when you have used content verbatim. From "Effective Modern C++" by Scott Meyers.

Comment: Sharing knowledge is a good thing. But you have to mention where you got it from especially if it involves using content from published copyrighted books.

Comment: If this whole answer is a quote, then the whole answer should be under quote formatting. It's not your work!

Comment: @P.W Edit the quote formatting in then ignore the plagiariser. Can't see a way for a chat to achieve anything. IME this is a cultural thing (up until you post on SE, then you are bound by policy and legality)

Answer (score 1):

[Auto type deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#auto_type_deduction) takes different rules for list-initialization. With copy-list-initialization, the template parameter **P** is considered as `std::initializer_list<U>`.

(emphasis mine)

> The parameter P is obtained as follows: in T, the declared type of the variable that includes auto, every occurrence of auto is replaced with an imaginary type template parameter U or, **if the initialization is copy-list-initialization, with `std::initializer_list<U>`**. The argument A is the initializer expression.

Then for `auto x = { 11, 23, 9 };`, the type of `x` would be `std::initializer_list<int>`.

For direct-list-initialization, the rule is different as:

> In direct-list-initialization (but not in copy-list-initalization), when deducing the meaning of the auto from a braced-init-list, the braced-init-list must contain only one element, and the type of auto will be the type of that element:
>
> ```
> auto x1 = {3}; // x1 is std::initializer_list<int>
> auto x2{1, 2}; // error: not a single element
> auto x3{3};    // x3 is int
>                // (before N3922 x2 and x3 were both std::initializer_list<int>)
> ```