# Trying to construct a vector from initializer list using std::make_unique()

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, smart-pointers, variadic, type-deduction

I struggle to understand the code below. Why can `v2` be constructed from an initializer list, but `v3` fails?

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
  auto v1 = std::make_unique<std::vector<int>>(std::vector<int>({1,2,3,4,5})); // works

  auto x = {1,2,3,4,5};
  auto v2 = std::make_unique<std::vector<int>>(x); // works

  //auto v3 = std::make_unique<std::vector<int>>({1,2,3,4,5}); // fails
}
```

Can someone explain, or point me to a resource that clarifies this behaviour?

Comment: One almost *never* need a pointer to a container. What is your use-case? What is the actual and underlying problem that is supposedly solved by using a pointer to the vector? This feels like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54476870/what-is-the-difference-between-auto-deduction-and-template-type-deduction?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for pointing me to the answer, @joergbrech.

Paraphrasing the answer: the reason is a subtle difference between auto type deduction and template type deduction:

From "Effective Modern C++" by Scott Meyers:

> `auto` type deduction is usually the same as template type deduction, but `auto` type deduction assumes that a braced initializer represents a `std::initializer_list`, and template type deduction doesn’t.